# How To Get Clone Project in Window 7 OS by command line

Tags: git

Hello friends i m trying to get clone project in windows but not getting it i use following command

```
 C:\>git clone https://code.google.com/p/quiz-and-poll/
```

get error message like

```
'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Any idea how can i get it?

Comment: What happens when you enter that command? Is there an error message?

Comment: No one can help you without information like what actually happens. "not getting it" is not a good description of what's happening when you run the command.

Comment: did you try with git bash console ?

Answer (score 1):

**Try running the command using the Git Bash**, the most likely cause for this problem is not having Git on your PATH, resulting in not being able to run `git` commands in the Windows Command Prompt.

Someone has written some instructions on their website [here](http://blog.countableset.ch/2012/06/07/adding-git-to-windows-7-path/), they will help you to add Git to your PATH. If you do not wish to add Git to your PATH, simply run the command using the Git Bash.